# Unable to post form details using Express js

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

My express code:

```
  var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser= require("body-parser");
    var app = express();
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    app.get('/', function(req, res){
            res.render('default', {title: 'Home', users: ['a', 'b', 'c']});
    });


    app.post('/me', function(req, res){
            res.send("2nd page");
            var t1= req.body.username;
            console.log(t1);
   });
```

My template:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/me">
   <input type="text" name="username">
   <input type="password" name="password">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I'm trying to print the form values in submitted page
I have not added any jQuery or anything in the head section
What's the mistake?

Comment: where do you want to print username ? is it in console

Comment: on the webpage. Its okay if i'm able to print in the console as-well. I just want to ensure that data is being pass on

Comment: On which port you are running your server, for example if its 8080 , use "localhost:8080/me" as action in the form

Comment: it doesn't work still

Comment: can you show your total server code

Comment: find the server code in the answer section

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your form enctype, I am using jade template system, just add "jade": "^1.6.0" in your package.json and do npm install

Server Code

```
  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();
  var bodyParser= require("body-parser");

  app.use(bodyParser.json());  
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

  app.set('view engine', 'jade');

  app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('test');
  });
  app.post('/me', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body.username);
    res.send("done");
  });

  app.listen(8081);
  console.log("Listening at 8081");
```

views/test.jade

```
 doctype html
 html
    form(method="post",enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/me")
    input(type="text",name="username")
    input(type="password" name="password")
    input(type="submit")
```

if you want multipart/form-data you need to use

```
var multer = require('multer'); app.use(multer())
```

Comment: does this worked,  copy my code and do npm install , create views folder and keep test.jade inside, and run server